# Can't add Resources/layout folder in shared Xamarin project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, shared-project

I'm working on shared project and needed to add `Resources/layout` folder but this leads me to error about this folder alredy existing.

In my project `Resources` folder only have `Drawable` and `values` subfolders. In actual file system here is also some alternative folders for drawables. But here is no `layout` folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Maybe it's fine to use different folder name? I can add `layout_` folder without errors.

Comment: No. It's just single project. And for some reason here is no layout folder.

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms` Shared project. It looks like `MyApp` plus `MyApp.Droid` project.

Comment: Do you mean I need to use `MyApp.Droid/Resources` folder? But this is what I'm trying to do. All my resources have `AndroidResource` build action.

Comment: Suddenly problem was solved somehow. Sorry for confusion made by my rush learning of Xamarin development. And thank you for response!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by removing code refering to not existing yet `Resource.Layout` and rebuilding solution.

Can't tell for sure what's actually solved a problem.